# Null Pointer Exception when trying to use (java.util.Random) in method - beginner Java

Tags: java, random, nullpointerexception

I'm currently trying to write a very simple program to test the capabilities of the "Random" class (java.util.Random) in a few ways, however I receive a Null Pointer Exception error when trying to run.

My code:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class RandomTester
{
    public Random r;

    public RandomTester()
    {
        Random r = new Random();
    }

    public void printOneRandom()
    {
        int s = 0;
        s = r.nextInt(256);  //NULL POINTER EXCEPTION HERE
        System.out.println("Random 8-bit number: " + s);

    }

    public void printMultiRandom(int howMany)
    {
        for(int i=0 ; i<howMany ; i++)
        {
            System.out.println("Random 8-bit number: " + r.nextInt(256));
        }    
    }

}
```

It works fine if I move the constructor from RandomTester() to either one of the methods but I was under the impression that writing it the above way should be okay.  It may well just be I'm not quite grasping something fundamental or indeed that I should have instantiate the object elsewhere.

Thank you for any help, there's no main method shown as I'm using BlueJ (a learner IDE).  It's also my first time exploring some of the basic classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this

```
Random r = new Random();
```

to

```
r = new Random();
```

You were previously initializing a different local variable that has a name that shadows your instance field. Your instance field was therefore initialized to a default value of `null`.

When you tried to use it in one of your methods, it was still `null` and gave you a `NullPointException` when you tried to dereference it to invoke a method.

Comment: So generally speaking, when writing my constructor I shouldn't put the class at the start (as the variable has already been initialised in the fields above)?

Comment: @Hoob There are different types of variables: local, instance, parameter, `catch` block, type, etc. You just need to know how and when to declare each one of those.

Comment: Would using a static code analysis tool or setting extra compiler options flag this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You're creating the variable inside of the constructor.  Use `this.r = new Random();` instead.

Comment: You do not actually need `this` here.

Comment: @PM77-1 True, can't argue that.  It's a force of habit with me and Java.